# Import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto" was not found scala

Tags: scala, sbt, protocol-buffers, grpc, scalapb

I have a `.proto` file which Imports `google/protobuf/wrappers.proto`
while I run Scalapbc to generate the relevant scala code out of it it gives Import `google/protobuf/wrappers.proto` not found error.

as a workaround for now I have kept the `wrappers.proto` file in file system for now inside `--proto_path`

But I need to come up with a fix wherein I need add the relevant dependencies in build.sbt / pom.xml to unpack the jar containing default proto files  (such as wrappers.proto) before calling Scalapbc

Comment: How are you building the gRPC stubs? Can you show the relevant parts of `build.sbt`?

Comment: @Tim I am using   // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc/grpc-protobuf
libraryDependencies += "io.grpc" % "grpc-protobuf" % "1.24.1"

Comment: I use `AkkaGrpcPlugin` which works well for me.

Comment: @Tim, oh okay.. but how does the import looking for wrappers.proto or any default proto files works for u? do u need to manually include them in file system or it automatically get included ?

Comment: I posted a full answer below, hope it helps. But, yes, includes of standard files works for me using this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

All the required dependencies are provided by scalabp runtime

```scala
import sbtprotoc.ProtocPlugin.ProtobufConfig
import scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapbVersion,
  "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapbVersion % ProtobufConfig
)
```

Comment: where to include this one? I tried including this in build.sbt but getting error

Comment: it needs to be included into project containing your protocol buffer files. also the `scalapb` plugin must be added to `plugins.sbt`. It seems you're missing more things than originally posted in your question

Answer (score 0):

I uses the `AkkaGrpcPugin` for `sbt` which seems to handle all the dependencies.

In `plugins.sbt` I have

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.akka.grpc" % "sbt-akka-grpc" % "1.1.1")
```

In `build.sbt` I have

```
enablePlugins(AkkaGrpcPlugin)
```

In automatically picks up the files in `src/main/protobuf` for the project and generates the appropriate stub files. I can import standard files, e.g.

```
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
```

For multi-project builds I use something like this:

```
lazy val allProjects = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(util, grpc)

lazy val grpc =
  project
    .in(file("grpc"))
    .settings(
      ???
    )
    .enablePlugins(AkkaGrpcPlugin)

lazy val util =
  project
    .in(file("util"))
    .settings(
      ???
    )
    .dependsOn(grpc)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I really appreciate it.

I was able to solve the dependency issue by

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                 <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                                 <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                                 <version>3.10.0</version>
                                 <type>jar</type>   
                              <includes>path/to/Files.whatsoever</includes>
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/foldername</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This generates the required proto files inside target folder

Comment: Your question contains tag `sbt` but your solution is for `maven`. Please provide sufficient information in the question next time.